# Find all Packages that uses Flat Files

Tags: sql, ssis

One of my coworkers was wondering if there is a way to get a list of all SSIS packages names on Integration services of all packages that uses FlatFiles.  There are currently a lot of packages on the server and it will take a very long time to find all packages manually.  We are using SQL 2008 r2.

Thank you

Comment: If you export all those packages to a .dtsx file you can just search in that text for the text file driver string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Export all packages from SSIS package store to files.
2. Search in .dtsx files for `<DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName">FLATFILE</DTS:Property>`. This is an integral part of any Flat File Connection Manager definition.

**Note** - this applies to 2005 and 2008 packages only!